# Передать значение из одной функции в другую

Tags: javascript

Как из функции `GetNewUserId` передать значение `id` в функцию `AddUser`

```
var usersData = [];

function AddUser(GetNewUserId, name, email) {
    usersData.push({
        id: userObj,
        name: name,
        email: email
    });
}

function GetNewUserId(id, userObj) {
    if (usersData.id === 0) {
        usersData.id = 1;
    } else {
        var maxId = usersData.reduce((max, item) => item.id > max ? item.id : max, 0);
        userObj['id'] = maxId + 1;
        usersData.push(userObj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы передать значение из одной функции в другую его можно:

- использовать при вызове функции как параметр (из вызывающей в вызываемую), или
- вернуть с помощью `return` (из вызываемoй в вызывающую).

```js
    var usersData = [];
    
    function AddUser(name, email) {
      usersData.push({
        id: GetNewUserId(),
        name: name,
        email: email
      });
    }
    
    function GetNewUserId() {
      var result = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < usersData.length; i++) {
        if (usersData[i].id > result)
          result = usersData[i].id;
      }
      return result + 1;
    }
    
    AddUser("Bob", "bob@world.com");
    usersData.push({id: 123, name: "Dick", email: "dick@world.com"});
    usersData.push({id: 67, name: "Rob", email: "rob@world.com"});
    AddUser("Harry", "harry@world.com");
    console.log(usersData);
```

Comment: а как реализовать с использованием старого метода генерации `id`. где ищется максимальный `id` среди всех пользователей и возвращает   `id + 1`, а если в массиве нет пользователей, возвращает 1. при добавлении пользователя id задается автоматически и начинается с 1

Comment: а все сам догадался :)